Unable to modify quote and verse blocks in org-mode
Although I have set org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks to t, when I call describe-text-properties with point on a #+begin_quote or #+begin_verse block the value of face remains org-block:
There are text properties here:
  face                 (org-block)
  font-lock-fontified  t
  font-lock-multiline  t
  fontified            t
  line-prefix          ""
  src-block            t
  wrap-prefix          ""

As a consequence, the face attributes I set for org-quote and org-verse are not reflected in these code blocks: e.g. the text is shown in fixed pitch font, despite having set a variable pitch font family for those faces.
A user reports a similar problem here.

Have you set the variable before loading the org file, as mentioned in one of the replies to the linked report?

Yes, it’s set in my init file. But perhaps the variable has to also be set before other face-related variables? Do you know if there is any such precedence requirement?

No idea. I'd try setting the variable in custom-set-variables, not using the ordinary setq.
